# FusionReactor ENT v5 WebRequest Runtime Protection Emails not working

Tags: coldfusion, fusionreactor

I have FusionReactor ENT v5 on my new server,

I have FusionReactor STD Edition v.5 on my old server.

The only problem I am having is that the WebRequest Runtime Protection is not working.

I have checked the settings,

http://docs.intergral.com/display/FR50/Protection+Settings

Request Runtime Protection Strategy

This defines what happens when this protection type is triggered. The individual survival strategies are defined as follows:

```
Abort (with Email Notification): Protection will attempt to abort any requests that have run for too long and have triggered Request Runtime Protection. Optionally sends an email notification containing details about the triggering request.
Email Notification Only: Send an email notification (as long as notification is enabled in FusionReactor Settings) but take no further action.
```

My reactor.conf from my old server:

```
fac.archive.retention.value=100
crashprotection.pagelist.0.track_stats=true
user.0=Administrator,administrator,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,?p\=running&static\=&flavor\=WebRequest&__toc\=requests
crashprotection.pagelist.0.string=/directory1/directory2/SiteFile1.cfm
crashprotection.pagelist.1.string=directory1/directory2/SiteFile2.cfm
crashprotection.pagelist.count=2
crashprotection.email.address.to=TEST@domain.com
crashprotection.pagelist.1.scope=ALL
version=7
crashprotection.pagelist.0.scope=TIMEOUT
fruid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
crashprotection.pagelist.1.track_stats=false
crashprotection.pagelist.1.regex=false
crashprotection.pagelist.0.regex=false
fac.archive.retention.strategy=SIZE
crashprotection.email.active=true
crashprotection.pagelist.0.append_parameters=false
crashprotection.requests.level.min=5
crashprotection.pagelist.1.prepend_hostname=false
crashprotection.pagelist.0.prepend_hostname=false
crashprotection.pagelist.1.append_parameters=false
fac.scheduler.mailjob.enable=true
crashprotection.email.server=127.0.0.1
crashprotection.request_timeout=60
crashprotection.email.address.from=fusionreactor@domain.com
gruid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

My reactor.conf from my new server:

```
user.0=Administrator,administrator,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
metrics.slow_threshold=2
crashprotection.email.active=true
crashprotection.email.server=127.0.0.1
crashprotection.request_timeout=10
email.hostname=local.domain.com
crashprotection.email.address.from=fusionreactor@domain.com
version=6
crashprotection.requests.level.min=5
metric.recent_slow_pages.statusthreshold.ok2w=1
crashprotection.email.address.to=testuser@omain.com
gruid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
fruid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The test email works fine and the crash notication email works fine.

The slow web request does not

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of things your new server config looks ok for the CrashProtection settings. It might just be that the Protection system has not taken the settings correctly.

Have your tried restarting your server?

It looks like there is a bug in the current FR 5 agent where the Crash Protection settings would not correctly update if Quantity protection is enabled. A server restart should correct this issue.

If you do not wish to restart your server, you can try putting all the protection settings back to the defaults, save them. Then setting up Runtime protection first.

Hopefully this will solve your issue.

If you have any other problems I suggest you contact the FusionReactor support team at support@fusion-reactor.com.

Kind Regards,

Ben Donnelly

FusionReactor Support